# Using Gridview in MVP pattern

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms, mvp

I am trying to implement the MVP design pattern for the first time, using webforms and SQL Server.

I want to use a Gridview to display data from the database.
However when I set the ControlSource of the Gridview from the Presenter, it makes the Default.aspx View dependent on the Dataset. This seems wrong, because if I swap my SQL database for something else, the view would have to change as the GridView might not work.

Is it bad practice to do this, if so how can it be avoided?

I have added my notes to help illustrate the problem (note the red arrow between DefaultView and Dataset):

[image: MVP datbase notes]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really can't understand why, having such rich model layer, would you ignore it and bind the view directly to a data set. Why on Earth you don't bind to a list of objects exposed in the model?

Grids in ASP.NET do fine if you bind to `IEnumerable`s, a list of object is fine. You could even have a thin adapter, the `ObjectDataSource` that controls the way a grid retrieves and updates the data to support sorting and paging.

So, answering your question:

> Is it bad practice to do this, if so how can it be avoided?

To me, the view peeks too deep under the cover, it actually peeks into internal details of the DAO implementation. You could avoid it by coupling the view to the model members instead of the model internals. And while your model looks OOP (Customer), data set sounds like the internal way the db access is implemented.

BTW. I would consider switching to an ORM like Entity Framework. It makes implementing object models much easier than introducing a layer of data sets.